# how to make a partition which is in ext-2 , a writable disk?

Tags: linux

i have debian system in which i have mounted the OS on a ext-3 system . I have got a partition of 60 gb , which is formatted to ext-2 partition . Even if I mount , i cant write anything into it . How can i change that ? How can I make the disk writable?

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't mount the partition read only, then you should be able to write to it once it's mounted. Except if the user trying to write does not have write permissions to it.

Comment: i am not really sure what should be the command to mount it as writable . And i am doing sudo when I mount it. so i think i have the permissions..

Comment: If you didn't wrote special options to the mount commands, then it is most likely the partition is mounted read/write. Check if your user has the permissions to write to the directory where the partition is mounted, or use superuser (sudo touch /path/to/mounted/directory/foo).

Answer (score 0):

The partition might need to be 'checked.' Run [fschk](http://www.netadmintools.com/html/8fsck.man.html) on the partition BEFORE IT IS MOUNTED.